# Closing empty tags, HTML, XML

Tags: html, xml, dom

I posed a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21613828/using-a-single-div-to-clear-a-float) some time ago and got a pretty good answer, now I would like to slightly modify that question in light of something I noticed while working with Google Maps.

The question is, I've always used `<div style="clear:both"></div>` to clear a float. There are other times when I've needed to create an empty element to be populated with JS, for example. Now, since HTML is a subset of XML, why can't I use `<div style="clear:both" />` instead of typing the ugly closing tag.

I was given a great answer that I admittedly don't fully understand in my previous question, but while working with Google Maps I noticed that [Google had the same idea that I did](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial). In their very first code sample, they use `<div id="map-canvas"/>` without the ending tag.

So my new question is, even if this is not quite proper HTML, would there ever realistically be case where this would not work?

Please and thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now, since HTML is a subset of XML

HTML is not a subset of XML.

HTML 4 and earlier were SGML applications, but browsers never implemented the SGML specification properly.

XHTML 1.x is an XML application, but browsers will only use XML parsing rules if you serve XHTML with an XML content-type (like `application/xhtml+xml`).

HTML 5 has its own parsing rules that better reflect what browsers actually do. It allows a `/` character at the end of elements where the end tag must be omitted for the sake of people who are addicted to XML or have poor syntax highlighting software, but only those elements.

> I noticed that Google had the same idea that I did. In their very first code sample, they use `<div id="map-canvas"/>` without the ending tag.

That is an error and is not allowed in HTML. It only "works" in browsers because the end of the document comes before the start of any element or text that is allowed as a child node of a div element.

> The question is, I've always used `<div style="clear:both"></div>` to clear a float.

That's a nasty approach to the problem in the first place. It requires an extra element, and can add space where the element is rendered. Better, in almost every case, to set `overflow: hidden` on the containing element to cause it to wrap the floats.

Answer (score 2):

HTML is not a subset of XML. HTML has a different structure. Some elements are singular (like image) and don't need a closing tag or ending `/` at all. The ones who do, need to be closed by a proper closing tag.

Some people use XHTML, though, which is basically HTML using XML syntax. It depends on the doctype you use.

Google's example is wrong in this case. It uses a Html 5 doctype. If you run their snippet through the [W3 validator](http://validator.w3.org/), it tells you:

> Line 26, Column 26: Self-closing syntax (/>) used on a non-void HTML
>   element. Ignoring the slash and treating as a start tag.
>       `<div id="map-canvas"/>`

And that's what will *probably* happen in most browsers as well. They read it as if the div is just opened there. At a certain point it will be automatically closed. The `/` is ignored.

About the clearing of floats: the way you are doing it is old, and ugly because you need extra markup, for what is basically a CSS issue. Fortunately, there are better ways, a couple of which are described in detail here: [What methods of ‘clearfix’ can I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/which-method-of-clearfix-is-best)